# Combining memoization and tail call optimization

Tags: python

I recently learned about a powerful way to use decorators to [memoize recursive functions](http://avinashv.net/2008/04/python-decorators-syntactic-sugar/). 
*"Hey that's neat, let's play with it!"*

```py
class memoize:
    """Speeds up a recursive function"""
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        self.memoized = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        try:
            return self.memoized[args]
        except KeyError:
            self.memoized[args] = self.function(*args)
            return self.memoized[args]
#fibmemo
@memoize
def fibm(n, current=0, next=1):
    if n == 0:
        return current
    else:
        return fibm(n - 1, next, current+next)
```

Which `timeit` shows this indeed speeds up the algorithm:

```
fibmemo     0.000868436280412
fibnorm     0.0244713692225
```

*"Wow, that could be really useful! I wonder how far I can push it?"*
I found when I start using inputs higher than 140, I quickly ran into `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. *"Ahh shucks.."*

After a little searching I [found a hack](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474088/) that appears to solve the problem.
*"This looks neat, too! Let's play with it"*

```py
class TailRecurseException:
    def __init__(self, args, kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

def tail_call_optimized(g):
    """
    This function decorates a function with tail call optimization. It does this by throwing an exception
    if it is it's own grandparent, and catching such exceptions to fake the tail call optimization.

    This function fails if the decorated function recurses in a non-tail context.
    """
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        f = sys._getframe()
        if f.f_back and f.f_back.f_back and f.f_back.f_back.f_code == f.f_code:
            raise TailRecurseException(args, kwargs)
        else:
            while 1:
                try:
                    return g(*args, **kwargs)
                except TailRecurseException, e:
                    args = e.args
                    kwargs = e.kwargs
    func.__doc__ = g.__doc__
    return func

#fibtail
@tail_call_optimized
def fibt(n, current=0, next=1):
    if n == 0:
        return current
    else:
        return fibt(n - 1, next, current+next)
```

Ok, so I have a way to speed up my fibonacci function using memoize.  I have a way to push the recursion limits. I can't figure out how to do both.

```py
#fibboth
@memoize
@tail_call_optimized
def fibb(n, current=0, next=1):
    if n == 0:
        return current
    else:
        return fibb(n - 1, next, current+next)
```

```py
fibboth     0.00103717311766 
fibtail     0.274269805675
fibmemo     0.000844891605448
fibnorm     0.0242854266612
```

I've tried combining the decorators which LOOKS like it works for inputs below 140, but the moment I go beyond that, `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` occurs. It's almost like the `@tail_call_optimized` fails.
*"What the...?"*

---

**QUESTION:**

1. Is there a way to combine these decorators?  If so, how?
2. Why when combined does it appear that the decorators are working for smaller inputs?

Comment: the example you gave isn't really tail call optimized. that's when you can make a function call without growing the stack. but you are growing the stack, you're just then raising an exception right after, which is also expensive. it's more a form of trampolining (see wheaties' answer) than tail call optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here:  the first is that, as @badcook points out, the memoize decorator technically transforms your function into a non-tail-recursive function.  However, the tail_call_optimized decorator doesn't care about that.

The second issue, and the reason it doesn't work, is that the memoize decorator adds an additional frame to the stack every time fibb is called.  So instead of being its own grand-parent, it is more like its own great-grand-parent.  You could fix the check, but be aware that the memoize decorator will be effectively bypassed.

So the morale of the story is that tail call optimization and memoization do not mix.

Of course, for this particular problem, there is a way to solve the problem in a logarithmic number of steps anyway (see SICP exercise 1.19 at http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.4 for more details), making the issue pretty moot in this case.  But that's not what this question is about.

Comment: This makes sense.  Would it be possible to combine the two into a single decorator thereby reaping the benefits of both?  I admit, I have no clue what that would look like if it is at all possible.

Comment: Not really.  The main issue is that memoized functions are inherently not tail recursive.  If you think about it, if there is no "memo" for a particular set of arguments, then the memoization code must call the underlying function and then *save the result*.  Therefore, the last operation done by the function is no longer a call to itself, but instead is the memoization of the result.  For arguments that have already been memoized, there is no need for the underlying function to be called at all.  So there really isn't any tail call to "optimize".

Answer (score 3):

@NathanDavis nailed it in his answer - you should accept it. `tail_call_optimized()` is nasty code, relying on two things:

1. That it knows exactly what the call stack looks like; and,
2. That it matters not one whit if it destroys part of the call stack.

If you apply it all on its own, to a truly tail-recursive function, those are fine.  But combine it with another decorator, and #1 is no longer true.  You can try to "repair" that, like this (for example):

```
def tail_call_optimized(g):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        f = sys._getframe()
        code = f.f_code
        fcount = 0
        while f:
            if f.f_code is code:
                fcount += 1
                if fcount > 1:
                    raise TailRecurseException(args, kwargs)
            f = f.f_back
        while 1:
            try:
                return g(*args, **kwargs)
            except TailRecurseException, e:
                args = e.args
                kwargs = e.kwargs
    func.__doc__ = g.__doc__
    return func
```

Now it searches back the call stack any number of frames to "find itself" again, and that indeed gets rid of the recursion-limit exception.  But, as Nathan implied, when it raises `TailRecurseException` that **also** gets rid of in-progress calls to the memoization decorator.  In the end, after calling (say) `fibb(5000)`, only argument 5000 will be in the memo.

You could complicate it yet again, to restitch the call stack to throw away *only* the in-progress calls to the `tail_call_optimized` decorator, and then the memo would work correctly again.  But - surprise! ;-) - then the call stack would still contain in-progress calls to all the levels of the memo decorator, and you'd hit the maximum recursion limit again.  Since the memo function itself does *not* end with a call (i.e., it's *never* correct to throw away a stack frame corresponding to a memo function call), there's no simple way to worm around that.

Answer (score 1):

What you're hitting is the stack limit in Python. What you need to do if you truly want to go this way is to start using something called a [Trampoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Through_trampolining). This essentially trades stack space for heap space.

There's a good article on how to think about these in [javascript](http://raganwald.com/2013/03/28/trampolines-in-javascript.html) and a more specific one for [Python](http://chuckha.com/blog/2013/05/03/building-a-trampoline-in-python/). From that article what you're looking for is this:

```
def trampoline(func):
  def decorated(*args):
    f = func(*args)
    while callable(f):
        f = f()
    return f
  return decorated
```

So that you can do things without blowing stack. Give it a read.

EDIT:

I'd also like to add that this is a naive implementation of a Trampoline. There are much better versions of these libraries, which is why I linked the js article. You can see within it a more powerful version which can handle many types of dependent computations while still retaining the idea of tail call optimization.

Comment: Tail call optimization is not about trading stack space for heap space. It is about eliminating the need for space at all, except for some constant amount. Also, the whole point of the tail_call_optimized decorator is to provide a trampoline for self-recursive functions -- its approach is a little different than traditional trampolines, but I think it's reasonable to argue it's a trampoline. It works by itself. The question is why it doesn't compose well with the memoize decorator.

Comment: @NathanDavis You're absolutely right about tail call optimization. Just because one decorator works in one way does not mean the answer to the question of how to get things working will involve it. I never said to use the `tail_call_optimized` decorator nor did I even mention the `memoize` decorator. I pointed to a different solution to explore.

Comment: I know you didn't say to use the tail_call_optimized decorator and that you did not mention the memoize decorator.  My point was that the combination of the two was essential to the question.

Comment: I don't think the above trampoline actually works: you see these floating around the web a lot but because the `func` will actually become `decorated`, stack frames grow and eventually blow the stack. Try this with a simple tail-recursive factorial and it should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the briefest of glances (need to run off right about now), my guess is that your memoize decorator has ruined the tail call (i.e. your function is no longer in the tail position), so that in fact the function is no longer tail call optimizable.